# Kitchen Water valve not shut off

Tags: repair, water

I search in google about how to shut off the water valve under the sink. And it say "turn counter-clockwise until it tight" and I did, but the water still running.

Comment: Did you see any influence at all on the water flow? Do you have two valves (cold/hot)?

Answer (score 3):

Remember "Lefty loosey righty tighty".  Turn the valve Clockwise (right) to close and counter clockwise (left) to open.

Comment: I did that but the water still running

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible situations.

- The valve stem has fractured, in this case you can turn the handle endlessly in either direction without any effect on flow and without ever reaching a point where the handle won't turn any further. Normally a handle would turn no more than three or four revolutions in each direction - fewer for some types of valve (tip - add a photo to the question)
- You didn't turn it far enough. Sometimes valves get stiff. You might think it reached the end of its travel before it has.
- You turned it the wrong way. Try both directions and carefully monitor rate of flow from the faucet.
- Wrong valve.
- The valve is the main stopcock for the building but water can back flow to the kitchen faucet from pipework in the rest of the building - particularly from upper floors. Check for other valves, especially if you have header tanks. wait 5 to 10 minutes after turning the valve fully in one direction to see if flow rate is slowing.